# Keeping track of shapes on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to find a suitable way to identify individual shapes on my canvas. I am creating a seat booking tool that allows the user to position rectangles on a grid that will hold seat location information somehow (seat number to start with).

At the moment I have a shape function :

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) { 
   this.x = x || 0;
   this.y = y || 0;
   this.w = w || 1;
   this.h = h || 1;
   this.fill = fill || '#AAAAAA';
 }
```

And a prototype to give the context

```
Shape.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
 }
```

For now, as I am purely in testing and trying to learn how to do this, I have set up a doubleclick event listener to run the following

```
canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
  for(var i=0; i <= 180; i += 20){  
      for(var j = 0; j <= 225; j += 25){            
           myState.addShape(new Shape(mouse.x + i, mouse.y + j, 15, 20, 'rgba(0,255,0,.6)'));       
    }}
 }, true);
```

My thinking behind this is as follows. Since a typical seating plan can contain hundreds if not thousands of seats, I will give the option to enter in the rows and columns of a block of seats and have the user delete the ones they don't need (also no real idea how to do that either) but for now I manually input rows and columns.

My question is, how do I assign each new shape created an id of sorts? someway to make each shape store a unique number to identify it's position?

Cheers in advance for any help.

I should mention I've looked at using pre existing libraries but can't seem to install them correctly (always just used links in the header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better off using SVG (http://raphaeljs.com/ is a great compatibility library that leverages SVG) to try to do this if the elements have to be interactive. Canvas has no way of identifying the drawn elements after they are drawn so you either have to use an individual canvas for each item or you have to redraw the entire canvas when a change is made.

Comment: Oh! Looks very good actually. Could you possibly ELI5 as to how this works? From what I gather it still uses canvas(?) but treats each shape as an object?

Comment: No, it uses scalable vector graphics on platforms that support that and VML on older IE platforms that do not support SVG